# how to improve the performance of the CNN model (Machine Learning - Deep Learning)

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to train a model based on CNN,

Training data is the image of lunar lander, but the performance of model is not good, the accuracy is about 45%, I try to add more layer to improve it, but it still doesn't work well, could any one provide some ideas about how to improve it.
Label: up down left right (0,1,2,3)
Sample rate: 0.1

[image]
The Training data has converted from image to data
[image]
Label:
[image]

here is some of my code:

```py
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', input_shape=(CHANNELS, ROWS, COLS), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))

model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation = 'softmax'))
.summary()
```

[image]

Comment: what is the training accuracy?

Comment: The prediction accuracy on training data is about 56%.

Comment: Your first goal should be to increase training accuracy. Please update the question with what you are predicting, how many epoch you have run, how much time it has taken for 56% accuracy, how many rows in dataset,

Comment: I have updated it

Answer (score 0):

I would experiment a lower dropout rate. Dropouts are used to prevent overfitting. It looks like your model isn't even fitting in the first place.